# If I pass fs.readFile to multiple files, are they read concurrently and then their attached callbacks called upon completion in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing more reading about the asynchronous architecture in Node and I need some help understanding how the **poll** phase in the event loop works with multiple file reads. Suppose I have some .txt files that I need my program to read:

```
import * as fs from 'node:fs';

let text1 = './file1.txt';
let text2 = './file2.txt';
let text3 = './file3.txt';

function readMyFiles() {
  fs.readFile(text1, () => console.log('text1 finished'))
  fs.readFile(text2, () => console.log('text2 finished'))
  fs.readFile(text3, () => console.log('text3 finished'))
}

readMyFiles();
```

Let's also say that it takes 300 ms to read `text1`, 200 ms to read `text2`, and 100 ms to read `text3`. When the operations are queued, are they all ran simultaneously? If so, would the callbacks be placed in the **poll** phase and invoked in the order that they are finished (text3 callback, then text2, then text1)? Or would each file read operation be processed synchronously and then their callbacks added? (text1 callback invoked after 300 ms, text2 after 200ms, and then text3 callback invoked after 100ms)

Thank you.

Comment: "*When the operations are queued*" - not sure what exactly you think is queued here.

Comment: "*are they all ran simultaneously?*" - yes, all files are read at once. "*would the callbacks be invoked in the order that [the reads] are finished*" - yes, that's the whole idea of asynchronous programming, and is what makes the callbacks necessary in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The I/O operations aren't queued. Node relays them to the operating system.

Most operating systems are multithreaded. In that case, the I/O operations do run simultaneously outside of Node.

Each time an I/O operation completes, the OS tells Node, who then queues the respective callback for execution in the next Poll phase of the Node Event Loop.

So, in your code, the callbacks are executed in the order they're added to the poll queue, which is the order their respective asynchronous functions finish running in the OS kernel.